# LBPHFaceRecognizer predict function always return 1

Tags: python, face-recognition, opencv

I am developing a facial recognition system and for that I have selected LBPH algorithm for doing the task. I have collected the sample images of user and trained it. The problem is while recognizing the face, the predict() of LBPHRecognizer always return same value for label but different value for confidence. Even if the face is unknown it returns 1.

Technologies I have been using : Python 3.7.4, OpenCV 4.1.2

#### Code to collect sample image

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
import requests
import time
from PIL import Image

 class CollectFaceWebCam():
    def __init__(self, sid):
        self.studentId = sid

        #capture webcam 
        self.LiveWebCamera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

        #pre-trained dataset (haar-cascade classifier)
        self.faceDataSet = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

        #sample image capture counter
        self.imgCounter = 0

        self.directoryName = 'sampleImgFolder'

        #check path 
        if not os.path.exists(self.directoryName):
            os.makedirs(self.directoryName)

        if not os.path.exists(self.directoryName + '/' + self.studentId):
            os.makedirs(self.directoryName + '/' + self.studentId)


    def gen(self):
        while True:
            condition, frame = self.LiveWebCamera.read() #capture frame

            img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#conversion to gray scale 

            #face detection 
            faces = self.faceDataSet.detectMultiScale(  # Detect face sizes
            img,
            scaleFactor=1.3,
            minNeighbors=5,
            minSize=(100, 100),
            flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
            )

            for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                end_crd_x = x + w  # face start coordinates
                end_crd_y = y + h  #face end coordinate

                #draw rectangle 
                #@parms image, start plot, end plot, thickness, color
                cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_crd_x, end_crd_y), (0, 255, 33), 1)


                #accepts multiple face        
                if len(faces) >= 0:

                    #face must be single in frame
                    if len(faces) == 1:
                        detectedImg = img[y:y + h, x:x + w]

                        #checking blurness of image 
                        blurValue = cv2.Laplacian(detectedImg, cv2.CV_64F).var()

                        #ignoring the blury images
                        if not blurValue <= 60:

                            newImg = img[y:y + h, x:x + w] #new img 
                            #saving the detected faces
                            filename = '{}\{}\{}\{}_{}'.format(os.getcwd(), self.directoryName, self.studentId, self.studentId, self.imgCounter) + '.jpg'
                            cv2.imwrite(filename, newImg)
                            self.imgCounter += 1

                    else:
                        cv2.putText(frame,"Multiple Face not allowed", (50,150), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (237, 20, 5), thickness=2)


            cv2.putText(frame,"Collecting Sample", (50,100), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (250, 250, 250), thickness=3)
            cv2.putText(frame,"Image Count " + str(self.imgCounter), (50,200), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 2, (237, 20, 5), thickness=2)

            cv2.imshow('Collecting Sample', frame) # display frames

            k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # capture when user press 'esc'
            if k == 27:
                break
            elif self.imgCounter == 110:
                break

        self.LiveWebCamera.release() #stop video capture
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() #close all windows


class CleanSampleImages():
    def __init__(self):
        self.faceDataset = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
        self.eyeDataset = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_eye.xml')
        self.targetFolder = 'sampleImgFolder'

    def checkFace(self):
        os.chdir(self.targetFolder) 
        for directory in os.listdir():
            os.chdir(directory)
            for files in os.listdir():
                imagePath = '{}/{}'.format(os.getcwd(), files)

                imagePil = Image.open(imagePath).convert('L')
                imageNumpy = np.array(imagePil) #conversion of normal image to numpy array

                #detect face 
                faces = self.faceDataset.detectMultiScale(imageNumpy)
                #deleting image file if face is not found 
                if not len(faces) == 1:
                    os.remove(files)
                    break

                for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                    #detect eye from selected 
                    eyes = self.eyeDataset.detectMultiScale(imageNumpy)
                    if not len(eyes) > 0 and len(eyes) <=2:
                        #deleting image file if eye count of image is less than 0 or more than 2
                        os.remove(files)
            os.chdir('../')
        os.chdir('../')    





#id must be in X-X-ID eg. a-b-342
t = CollectFaceWebCam('sa-t-1')
t.gen()
clean = CleanSampleImages
c.checkFace()
```

Above code consist of two class CollectFaceWebCam and CleanSampleImages. CollectFaceWebCam works for collecting the sample images. and CleanSampleImages works for cleaning the collected data. if the image does not consist of face the file is deleted.

#### Code to Train images

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

class Trainer():
    def __init__(self):
        self.recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
        self.targetImagesDirectory="sampleImgFolder"
        self.dataset = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')      
    def getImgwithId(self):
        sampleImage, sampleImageId = [], []
        filename = '{}\\{}'.format(os.getcwd(), self.targetImagesDirectory)

        if os.path.exists(filename):
            os.chdir(filename)
            print('current path is ' + os.getcwd())
            for f in os.listdir():
                imgPath = os.path.join(filename, f)
                os.chdir(imgPath)
                for file in os.listdir():
                    #reteving id  from filename (filename format : ta-s-ID_Filename.jpg)
                    id = file.split('_')
                    id = id[0].split('-')
                    id = id[2]
                    imageFilePath = imgPath + '\\' + file

                    imagePil = Image.open(imageFilePath).convert('L')

                    #conversion to numpy array
                    imageNp = np.array(imagePil, 'uint8')

                    faces = self.dataset.detectMultiScale(imageNp)
                    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
                        sampleImage.append(imageNp)
                        sampleImageId.append(id)
                os.chdir('../')
            os.chdir('../')
        return sampleImage, np.array(sampleImageId, dtype = int)

def train(self, data, label):
    try:
        self.recognizer.train(data, label)
        self.msg = 'Training Successful'
        print('writting')
        self.recognizer.write('date.yml')
        print('writing finished')
    except:
        self.msg = 'Core: Training Error'
        print('except')

tr = Trainer()
sampleFaces, sampleFaceId = (tr.getImgwithId())
tr.train(sampleFaces, sampleFaceId)
```

#### Code to recognize face

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

class Recognizer():
def __init__(self):
    self.recognizer = cv2.face.LBPHFaceRecognizer_create()
    self.recognizer.read('date.yml')
    self.targetImagesDirectory="sampleImgFolder"
    self.dataset = cv2.CascadeClassifier('resources/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')      

    self.captureVideo = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    self.font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX = 2  # Font
    self.predictedUser = []

def gen(self):
    while True:
        condition, frame = self.captureVideo.read() #capture frame

        img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)#conversion to gray scale 

        #face detection 
        faces = self.dataset.detectMultiScale(  # Detect face sizes
        img,
        scaleFactor=1.3,
        minNeighbors=5,
        minSize=(100, 100),
        flags=cv2.CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE
        )

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            end_crd_x = x + w  # face start coordinates
            end_crd_y = y + h  #face end coordinate

            #draw rectangle 
            #@parms image, start plot, end plot, thickness, color
            cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (end_crd_x, end_crd_y), (0, 255, 33), 1)

            predictUser, confidence = self.recognizer.predict(img[y:y+h,x:x+w])
            self.predictedUser.append(predictUser)

        cv2.imshow('test', frame)

        k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # capture when user press 'esc'
        if k == 27:
            break

    self.captureVideo.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

r = Recognizer()
r.gen()
print(r.predictedUser)
```

**"predictUser, confidence = self.recognizer.predict(img[y:y+h,x:x+w])"** line of code in Recognizer class always return same value for label. The output of code to recognize face is attached below:
[image]

I would love to know why and where the problem is, as My skills and research could not lead me to identification of problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might because of the data-collection process. I see you using a cascade classifier multiple times, you could limit it. While checking for a face on webcam, you could use classifiers at the time and store only the extracted/cropped faces. Also during prediction, use confidence as a threshold to limit the false prediction.